# thread communication

Tags: java, multithreading

Am stuck in a bad situation, in my code, have two threads, one thread updates a table lets say table name as table1 and another thread updates table2. Now I have to update table3, but the job has to be done by thread 1. But it will not start working on table3 until and unless thread 2 finishes it works on table2. How to inform thread1 that thread2 already finished it work on table2, so you can strat work on table 3. How to build this communication among this two threads. I am developing in java if possible give me the answer with code speck.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)  that is shared between the threads.

The javadoc has an example.